# php soap_client handle long return

Tags: php

Hy I have a problem, i receve a sid over a soap call.
The problem is this is a xsp:long(64bit) php can't handle this and casts it to a double.
I tried to convert this to a gmp value but this fails after all?!

Can some one tell me on how i get this to work?

```
$sccsystem = new SoapClient($baseurl."/Services1.0/services/sccsystem?wsdl");
$sccrequirements = new SoapClient($baseurl."/Services1.0/services/tmrequirementsmanagement?wsdl");

//login:
try {
    $sessionid = $sccsystem->logonUser("user", "pw"); // tryed to use gmp_init but no success)
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "ACCESS DENIED!\n".$e."\n";
    exit(1);
}

echo "ACCESS GARANTED! [".$sessionid."]\n";

echo "tryReadingProjectList:\n";
var_dump($sccrequirements->getProjects($sessionid));
```

I also installed a 64bit version from: http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.6.3-nts-Win32-VC11-x64.zip with no luck :(
Here is the overview of the download page:http://windows.php.net/download/

Comment: Hm... if your OS it 64bit, and PHP is 64bit, and you still have problems, perhaps you still have a 32bit libxml? (http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/64bit/)

Comment: Hy Thanks for your reply probably that could be the problem. I downloaded the libxml2-2.9.2-win32_64.7z version. Where should this be placed if i search my hdd to libxml i get no match :S

Comment: Finaly i got it to work i build the whole php and the plugin dlls by hand now it works but don't ask me whats the diffrence to the binary above :S